# How to calculate on road distance between two points?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android app I am planning to add delivery taxes for the products(X bucks per kilometer) so, how can i calculate the on road distance between two points ?

Our products will be dispatched from a fixed location, but the user will give the destination location.

Can anyone give a detailed approach for this?

Comment: Comment if you dont understand my question

Comment: List out code which you have tried till now.

Comment: this side will help you https://inducesmile.com/android/android-find-distance-and-duration-between-two-points-on-android-map/

Comment: I am not sure where to start, I mean there are different approaches like the first answer given by Jay and there are other options using google maps API , so I am asking this question to know how to do it, I haven't done any code Yet.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [google map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) for that.
You will get response like this:

```
{
  "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
  "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
  "rows" : [
    {
      "elements" : [
        {
          "distance" : {
            "text" : "225 mi",
            "value" : 361715
          },
          "duration" : {
            "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
            "value" : 13725
          },
          "status" : "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

You can also use latitude and longitude if you want.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Google maps API and use polyLines, just call **.getDistanceValue()** to get the distance. the code below will show you how to show distance value in a textview calculating 2 points in the map.

```
 private List<Polyline> polylines;
private static final int[] COLORS = new int[]{R.color.primary_dark_material_light};
@Override
public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex) {
    if(polylines.size()>0) {
        for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
            poly.remove();
        }
    }

    polylines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <route.size(); i++) {

        int colorIndex = i % COLORS.length;

        PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(COLORS[colorIndex]));
        polyOptions.width(10 + i * 3);
        polyOptions.addAll(route.get(i).getPoints());
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
        polylines.add(polyline);

        TextView friendDist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);

        //following line will generate the distance
        friendDist.setText("Distance: "+ route.get(i).getDistanceValue() +" meters");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will accept the starting point lat lng and destination point lat lng and retunrn distance in KM

```
 public static double calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(double startLat, double startLong, double endLat, double endLong) {
    double earthRadiusKm = 6372.8; //Earth's Radius In kilometers
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(endLat - startLat);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(endLong - startLong);
    startLat = Math.toRadians(startLat);
    endLat = Math.toRadians(endLat);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(startLat) * Math.cos(endLat);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double haverdistanceKM = earthRadiusKm * c;
    return haverdistanceKM;
}
```

Comment: will this give on road distance?(i dont want aerial distance thats why )

Comment: may be not .. for that you have to use google api to calculate the distance