# How to snap coordinates to road and calculate distance

Tags: python, geolocation, location, openstreetmap

maybe somebody knows something, since I am not able to find anything that makes sense to me.
I have a dataset positions (lon, lat) and I want to snap them to the nearest road and calculate the distance between them.

So far I discovered OSM, however I can't find a working example on how to use the API using python.

If any of you could help, I am thankful for ever little detail.

Will try to find it out by myself in the meantime and publish the answer if successful (couldn't find any similar question so maybe it will help someone in the future)

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922369/how-to-calculate-on-road-distance-between-two-points)

Comment: For python, there are functions to calculate distance between points, and also it is possible to calculate distance between a point and a line segment defined by 2 lat/long pairs. If the road is defined by points, or line segments, its possible to calculate this. How many points do you need to snap?

Comment: Now it gets tricky, about 600k

Comment: 600k is still allright, but it depends how the roads are encoded. Can you give a data sample of roads and points to snap?

Comment: so far I am trying to snap it to an osm file, which contains all railways of Europe. Using osmnx, however the file seems to be to big, since i am not able to load the whole osm file.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! OSM is a wonderful resource, but is essentially a raw dataset that you have to download and do your own processing on. There are a number of ways to do this, if you need a relatively small extract of the data (as opposed to the full planet file) the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) is the place to look. [Overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) ([docs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo)) is a useful tool to help with this API.

Once you have the road network data you need, you can use a library like [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io) to [snap](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#snapping) your points to the road network geometry, and then either calculate the distance between them (if you need "as the crow flies" distance), or [split](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#splitting) the road geometry by the snapped points and calculate the length of the line. If you need real-world distance that takes the curvature of the earth into consideration (as opposed to the distance as it appears on a projected map), you can use something like [Geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy).

You may also want to look into the [Map Matching API from Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/map-matching-api/) (full disclosure, I work there), which takes a set of coordinates, snaps them to the road network, and returns the snapped geometry as well as information about the route, including distance.

Answer (score 0):

You might use KDTree of sklearn for this. You fill an array with coordinates of candidate roads (I downloaded this from openstreetmap). Then use KDTree to make a tree of this array. Finally, use KDTree.query(your_point, k=1)  to get the nearest point of the tree (which is the nearest node of the coordinate roads). Since searching the tree is very fast (essentially log(N) for N points that form the tree), you can query lots of points.